# JSON body in Spring Boot's @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that accepts a JSON string in the body of the Http request. I made the controller like this

```java
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMapping.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "/foo")
   public void acceptPost(@RequestBody TestModel t) {
        ....
   }
```

My JSON string is like this

```
    {
        "name" : "ABC",
        "age" : 20
    }
```

Spring Boot is able to marshal the request body into the `TestModel` POJO. But I am interested in doing the following

```java
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMapping.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "/foo")
    public void acceptPost(String name, Integer age) {
        ....
    }
```

The `name` and `age` comes in as arguments without there being an intermediate object to hold the JSON string as it was passed.

Is there any annotation that can be used or a way to override the existing interfaces or annotations in Spring Boot to help me get what I want?

Comment: There is no out of the box way to do what you want. You need to write a custom Method Argument Handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did what you suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everyone but still if you don’t want to create a pojo class, Get it as a JSON string @RequestBody String json.

Later use ObjecMapper to parse it as a Map then use the key to get the value. This is not required but this is another way of implementing it.

Comment: I followed what @shazin suggested in his comment. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing is correct. This is the advisable way to do, actually and type safe way too. And you can use `@PostMapping` annotation(which also supports `consumes` property) instead of `@RequestMapping`

Answer (score 0):

No, if it would have been normal query/path params or request body, then this kind of mapping was possible.

JSON is not 'universal' HTTP transfer object, hence no framework would ideally support String-within-a-JSON to String and Integer-within-a-JSON to Integer kind of out-of-the-box mapping.

Either you could have a class to get the deserialized JSON object OR you yourself could play around with query/path params or simply the request body.